# NetBIOS domain of computer in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, wmi, netbios

How can I get the NetBIOS (aka 'short') domain name of the current computer from PowerShell?

$ENV:USERDOMAIN displays the domain of the current user, but I want the domain that the current machine is a member of.

I've discovered you can do it [pretty easily in VBScript](http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/scripts/vbscript_display_netbios_domain_name.aspx), but apparently [ADSystemInfo isn't very nice to use](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730963.aspx) in PowerShell.

*Update*

Here's my final solution incorporating the suggestion of using [Win32_NTDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but filtering to the current machine's domain

```
$wmiDomain = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTDomain -Filter "DnsForestName = '$( (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain)'"
$domain = $wmiDomain.DomainName
```

Comment: For those who get multiple domains with David's answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21284636/1001100.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In most cases, the default NetBIOS domain name is the leftmost label in the DNS domain name up to the first 15 bytes (NetBIOS names have a limit of 15 bytes).
The NetBIOS domain name may be changed during the installation of the Active Directory, but it cannot be changed.

The WIN32_ComputerSystem WMI object gives informations on a Windows computer

```
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem

Domain              : WORKGROUP
Manufacturer        : Hewlett-Packard
Model               : HP EliteBook 8530w (XXXXXXXXX)
Name                : ABCHPP2
PrimaryOwnerName    : ABC
TotalPhysicalMemory : 4190388224
```

So the domain Name is given by :

```
PS C:\> (gwmi WIN32_ComputerSystem).Domain
```

But in domain installation, the DNS name is given. In this case, you can use `nbtstat -n` command to find the NetBIOS domain name which is displayed like this `<DOMAIN><1B>`.

The PowerShell Command may be :

```
nbtstat -n | Select-String -Pattern "^ *(.*) *<1B>.*$" | % {$_ -replace '^ *(.*) *<1B>.*$','$1'}
```

Here is another way using WMI

```
PS C:\> (gwmi Win32_NTDomain).DomainName
```

Comment: I already tried that approach and it doesn't work. The 'Domain' property is not the short/NetBIOS name that I'm after. That contains the full AD domain name

Comment: I tried this and for mine it shows as <1E> (rather than <1B>)

Comment: According to [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961857.aspx) it can be <00>, <1B>, <1C>, <1D>, <1E> so you can change the regular expression to "^ *(.*) *<1[BCDE]>.*$"

Comment: What about Win32_NTDomain WMI object

Comment: That one looks good in my environment.  I like it lots better than the convoluted answer I gave.  :-)

Comment: Win32_NTDomain looks like a winner. Note that returns multiple entries, including one for the local computer and probably other trusted domains (if you have any)

Answer (score 11):

Use `env:` to get environment settings through PowerShell

NetBIOS:  `$env:userdomain`

FQDN:     `$env:userdnsdomain`

To see all the values:

```
dir env:  (no $)
```

Comment: That answer is already mentioned in my question. It doesn't return the domain of the COMPUTER though (which is what I was asking)

Comment: There is `USERDOMAIN` and `USERDNSDOMAIN`. The second one did the job for my task.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 6):

```
import-module activedirectory
(Get-ADDomain -Identity (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain).NetBIOSName
```

Answer (score 4):

From [Here](http://www.rlmueller.net/NameTranslateFAQ.htm#PowerShell%20example)

```
# Retrieve Distinguished Name of current domain.
$Domain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
$Root = $Domain.GetDirectoryEntry()
$Base = ($Root.distinguishedName)

# Use the NameTranslate object.
$objTrans = New-Object -comObject "NameTranslate"
$objNT = $objTrans.GetType()

# Invoke the Init method to Initialize NameTranslate by locating
# the Global Catalog. Note the constant 3 is ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC.
$objNT.InvokeMember("Init", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $objTrans, (3, $Null))

# Use the Set method to specify the Distinguished Name of the current domain.
# Note the constant 1 is ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779.
$objNT.InvokeMember("Set", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $objTrans, (1, "$Base"))

# Use the Get method to retrieve the NetBIOS name of the current domain.
# Note the constant 3 is ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4.
# The value retrieved includes a trailing backslash.
$strDomain = $objNT.InvokeMember("Get", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $objTrans, 3)
```

Comment: FYI I tried this on Windows PowerShell on Windows 10 20H2 and the first line fails with Exception calling "GetCurrentDomain" with "0" argument(s): "Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest."

Answer (score 3):

OP is after "computer domain" so the answer would be `$GetComputerDomain` (below) but I will add the $GetUserDomain also for reference.

```
$GetComputerDomain = ([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetComputerDomain()).Name
$GetUserDomain = ([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()).Name
```

I find the wmi (gwmi) option to be extremely slow, especially, when you are querying the Win32_NTDomain class.  I have a multi-trusted domain environment and it takes forever when I just need that simple info quick.

Comment: Sorry, that's not the results I was after. Those both return a full DNS-style domain name. I was after the short/NetBIOS-style domain name.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Active Directory Cmdlet Get-ADDomain:

```
(Get-ADDomain -Current LocalComputer).NetBIOSName
```

Comment: That looks like a varation on @Sacha's answer

Comment: Yeah, it is similar.  Mine just has less keystrokes :)

Comment: Ha! Well I guess it is true that you only have a limited number of those to use up http://keysleft.com/  :-)

Comment: Good grief, I hope I'm still not working at the age of 90! lol

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done by using .NET framework (which is much faster than WMI)

```
PS > [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties()
```

Will return

```
HostName      : SurfaceBook
DomainName    : mydomain.com
NodeType      : Hybrid
DhcpScopeName :
IsWinsProxy   : False
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the ADSystemInfo COM object should work, with no delay from Win32_NTDomain lookup:

```
[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("DomainShortName", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty, $null, (New-Object -ComObject "ADSystemInfo"), $null)
```

There are other AD-related properties available from this COM object too:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/iadsadsysteminfo-property-methods

[EDITED - Updated to use ADSystemInfo - in response to a comment that WinNTSystemInfo only returns the *user's* short domain]

Comment: That looks like it's returning the user's domain, not the machine's domain

Comment: @DavidGardiner Have checked today & the WinNTSystemInfo's DomainName property does return the user's domain, not the machine's domain. But the ADSystemInfo DomainShortName property is as you wanted it to be. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another faster method than Win32_NTDomain, for getting the NetBIOS domain of the computer.

```
# Get the computer system CIM/WMI
$computersystem = Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem

# Create a Windows Identity Principal object based on the name and domain in Win32_ComputerSystem
$ComputerPrincipal = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::new("$($computersystem.name)@$($computersystem.domain)")

# Split the NetBIOS name on \ and get the first value which should be the domain
($ComputerPrincipal.Name -split "\\")[0]


# Bonus point, the WindowsIdentity Principal has a bunch of other useful information.
# Like quick enumeration of the groups it's in (but needs to be translated from SID to NTAccount format).
$ComputerPrincipal.Groups.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).value
```

Answer (score 0):

The below powershell command works great! I tested after trying various solutions.

If you use the following .Net command:

```
 [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress('192.168.1.101').hostname
```

It works too, but it is using DNS to resolve, in my case, we have WINS setup to support an application that requires it, so can't use it. Below is what I ended up using as part of a script I use to check for WINS registration for each client:

```
$IPAddress = "<enterIPAddress>" (remove brackets, just enter IP address)

(nbtstat -A $IPAddress | ?{$_ -match '\<00\>  UNIQUE'}).Split()[4]
```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f52eb2c7-d55d-4d31-ab4e-09d65d366771/how-to-process-cmd-nbtstat-a-ipaddress-output-and-display-the-computer-name-in-powershell?forum=ITCG

The above link has the thread and conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NetGetJoinInformation` and P/Invoke:

```
Add-Type -MemberDefinition @"
[DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr Buffer);
[DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int NetGetJoinInformation(
  string server,
  out IntPtr NameBuffer,
  out int BufferType);
"@ -Namespace Win32Api -Name NetApi32

function GetDomainName {
  $pNameBuffer = [IntPtr]::Zero
  $joinStatus = 0
  $apiResult = [Win32Api.NetApi32]::NetGetJoinInformation(
    $null,               # lpServer
    [Ref] $pNameBuffer,  # lpNameBuffer
    [Ref] $joinStatus    # BufferType
  )
  if ( $apiResult -eq 0 ) {
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($pNameBuffer)
    [Void] [Win32Api.NetApi32]::NetApiBufferFree($pNameBuffer)
  }
}
```